# Passing a string define for gcc from the command line that starts with decimals (invalid suffix on integer constant)

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Consider this example, `test_print.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef MYVERSION
#define MYVERSION ""
#endif

// SO:1562074
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

#pragma message( " MYVERSION " XSTR(MYVERSION))

int main(void) {
  printf("MYVERSION is: '%s'", MYVERSION);
}
```

If I compile this without defining MYVERSION on the command line, all works as expected:

```
$ gcc test_print.c -o test_print.exe
test_print.c:11:9: note: ‘#pragma message:  MYVERSION ""’
   11 | #pragma message( " MYVERSION " XSTR(MYVERSION))
      |         ^~~~~~~

$ ./test_print.exe
MYVERSION is: ''
```

So far so good.

Now I want to set the MYVERSION define to the string "60c5158" - but with that change, compilation fails:

```
$ gcc -DMYVERSION=$(echo 60c5158) test_print.c -o test_print.exe
test_print.c:11:9: note: ‘#pragma message:  MYVERSION 60c5158’
   11 | #pragma message( " MYVERSION " XSTR(MYVERSION))
      |         ^~~~~~~
test_print.c: In function ‘main’:
<command-line>: error: invalid suffix "c5158" on integer constant
test_print.c:14:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘MYVERSION’
   14 |   printf("MYVERSION is: '%s'", MYVERSION);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
```

So, apparently the problem is, that "60c5158" starts with "60" which is interpreted as an integer; so I thought about quoting on the command line, but that does not work either:

```
$ gcc -DMYVERSION="$(echo 60c5158)" test_print.c -o test_print.exe
test_print.c:11:9: note: ‘#pragma message:  MYVERSION 60c5158’
   11 | #pragma message( " MYVERSION " XSTR(MYVERSION))
      |         ^~~~~~~
test_print.c: In function ‘main’:
<command-line>: error: invalid suffix "c5158" on integer constant
test_print.c:14:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘MYVERSION’
   14 |   printf("MYVERSION is: '%s'", MYVERSION);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
```

So, how can I pass MYVERSION of "60c5158" to gcc from the command line?

Comment: `MYVERSION=$(echo 60c5158)`?? Just `MYVERSION=60c5158`. `how can I pass MYVERSION of "60c5158" to gcc from the command line?` You are passing it. The line becomes `printf("MYVERSION is: '%s'", 60c5158);`, so it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found it as I was writing the question - turns out, the define *itself must have  quotation marks*, so this is the correct call:

```
$ gcc -DMYVERSION="\"$(echo 60c5158)\"" test_print.c -o test_print.exe
test_print.c:11:9: note: ‘#pragma message:  MYVERSION "60c5158"’
   11 | #pragma message( " MYVERSION " XSTR(MYVERSION))
      |         ^~~~~~~

$ ./test_print.exe
MYVERSION is: '60c5158'
```

Comment: Or alternatively `printf("MYVERSION is: '%s'", XSTR(MYVERSION));`